# How can I access or call or extract elements of a univariate time series data in python with Date and Data column

Tags: python, pandas

I want a python way to extract element in a column of my indexed time series data imported through pandas as I would do `df[data].values` in a data frame

I have this Minimum Workin Example

```
data = [1, 1.5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 16, 1]

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
date_rng = pd.date_range(start='01/2018', end='09/2018', freq='M')
len(date_rng)
```

Create a data frame

```
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = data
df.head(5)
```

Export the data frame as CSV

```
df.to_csv(r'C:/Users/user/Documents/Assignment 1.csv', index=False)
```

Import the CSV file as indexed time-series data

```
ts = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/user/Documents/Assignment 1.csv", parse_dates=['date'], index_col='date')
ts.head()
```

I want a python code like `ts[data].values` just as `ts.index` produces the date elements in the `date column`, to extract elements of the data column like one would do with data from. I expect result as the bellow:

```
# output [1, 1.5, 2, 4, 6, 8, 16, 1]
```

I have tried `ts.get_values` and `ts.data` all produce data with the date columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want your output specifically as a list instead of an array, use `.tolist()`:

```
ts['data'].values.tolist()
```

```
[1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 4.0, 6.0, 8.0, 16.0, 1.0]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
In: ts['data'].values
Out: array([ 1. ,  1.5,  2. ,  4. ,  6. ,  8. , 16. ,  1. ])
```

Is that not what you want?